# Write filenames to csv with Pandas and Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

How do I write a list of filenames to a column in a csv file, using Pandas? I also want to Regex to keep only a part of the filename.

With the csv module, I have done like this:

```
import os
import re
import csv

with open("file.csv","w") as write_csv:
    fieldnames = ["col1", "col2"]
    wr_header = csv.DictWriter(write_csv, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    wr_header.writeheader()
    wr_data = csv.writer(write_csv, delimiter = "\n")
    folder = os.listdir("/User/folder")
    for filename in folder:
        filesnippet = re.findall("snippet_(.{12})", filename)
        wr_data.writerow(filesnippet)
```

Comment: can you specify if your code works and what errors it throws if not?

Comment: @WajdiFarhani It's more that I don't know how to work Pandas. Something like this? `folder = os.listdir("/User/folder");
df = DataFrame(folder);
for filename in df:
 isin_source = re.findall("filesnippet_(.{12})", filename);
 filename.to_csv("file.csv")`

Comment: Do you expect `findall` to return a list with a variable number of elements? or can we assume it always finds one match?

Comment: Findall returns a variable list of elements, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas dataframe can take a list as a constructor. The real question is where do you do the regex work. Here, I use the pandas string method `extract` which returns the captured group for each row.

```
pd.Series(os.listdir(directory)).str.extract(regex).to_csv(filename)
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html